# How to achieve Data Sharding in Endeca (data partitioning)

Tags: sharding, endeca, oracle-commerce

Currently Oracle Commerce Guided Search (Endeca) supports only language specific partitions (i.e., One MDEX per Language).  For systems with huge data volume base (say ~100 million records of ~200 stores), does anyone successfully implemented data partitioning (sharding) based on logical group of data (i.e., One MDEX per group-of-stores) so that the large set of data can be divided into smaller sets of data?

If so, what precautions to be taken while indexing data and strategies for querying the Assembler?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a `Federated Search` or `Enterprise Search` where your data sources all happen to have the same data type. The actual solution would be very specific to your data and to explain it here will take more than what can be done in an SO answer. Suffice to say it can be done with Oracle Commerce and Oracle Commerce Guided Search.

Comment: @radimpe - Any links/pointers to such design would be much appreciated, as Googling is not helping here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this is possible.  Endeca used to support the Adgidx which allowed you to split or shard the mdex but that is no longer supported.  Oracles justification for removing this is that with multithreading and multi-core processors it is no longer necessary.  Apache Solr, however, supports sharing

Answer (score 1):

The large set of data can be broken into smaller sets, where each set would be attributed to a property, say record.type, which would identify the different sets. So, basically we are normalizing the records in the Endeca index.

Now, while querying endeca, we can use the concept of record relationship navigation queries, using record-record relationships by applying a relationship filter, to bring back records of different types.
However, you might have to obtain a RRN license to enable the RRN feature in the mdex engine.